# Error: Could not find or load main class com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher

Tags: 14.04, instant-messaging

I am trying to install spark client IM in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, but it throws the following error:

> Could not find or load main class
>   com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher

I performed step 1 from this link https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-im-voip-server-using-openfire-ubuntu-1404 but it still shows same error.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Just `mv .install4j` from where you extract spark to `/opt/spark`:

```
mv ~/Downloads/Spark/.install4j /opt/spark/
```